# How to save an action in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, designers, actions

How save an action in Photoshop and when we are upgrading version can we get the save actions on new version or we have to migrate the old actions files?

Comment: Hi Richardson, welcome to GDSE. I don't mean to be rude, but [Let Me Google That For You](https://www.google.nl/search?q=How+to+save+an+action+in+photoshop%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=9dfZVIuKK8HsUJa4gpAP): 18 million plus results on your question title alone. Please show some effort and do your research before posting a question. Thank you! Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you! Please check the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to save an action in Photoshop.

In the Actions panel, click the Create New Action button.

[image]

In the New Action dialog box, name the action (in my case) Blue Filter, and click Record.

[image]

Don’t let the fact that you’re recording rush you. Take all the time you need
to do this procedure accurately. he speed at which you work has no inluence
on the amount of time required to play a recorded action.

Click the Stop button (red dot ) at the bottom of the Actions panel to stop recording. The action you just recorded is now saved in the Actions panel. Click the arrows to expand different sets of steps. You can examine each recorded step and the specific selections you made.

[image]